Accidentally wore my sweaty T-shirt from days ago this morning. What can I do to get rid of the smell for the rest of the day?
This morning my sleep-deprived brain mixed a T-shirt into the clean pile of clothes, which then I subsequently took up and left to work. As time passed, I started to smell the unmistakeable scent of decay and death emitted by my choice of fashion, which makes sense as I sweated through a whole weekend day outside in it just a few days ago. I proceeded to spay an unhealthy amount of parfume onto myself, but it's just not enough to hide this aura of a death metal guitarist I'm bearing.
Any trick to at least reduce the smell for the rest of the day?

The best approach is to wash the shirt. Go into the bathroom, take it off, rinse it throughout, then use hand soap and water on the arm pits and anywhere else you typically sweat enough to make a shirt wet (eg on the back or neck area.) Soap kills the bacteria that were living on the fabric and producing the smell. Rinsing removes the smell molecules they have already produced.
Rinse it thoroughly and wring it out well. Then use the hand blower in the bathroom to dry it at least somewhat. It will probably still be damp when you put it back on, but as long as you don't leave wet spots on chairs, people probably won't notice.
Disclaimer: this won't work in a place with a more formal dress code, even "business casual". But in a Tshirt place you should be fine. Also, if you're a woman, wearing a damp tshirt may be more of a problem than it is for a man. Take the time to dry it completely in that case.
Longer term fix: keep a clean shirt in your desk, or in your bag if you don't have a desk. It's also useful if you spill your lunch down the front of yourself.

Heartily seconding the backup shirt strategy for the future!

Deodorant works best on freshly washed skin. It's not very effective at neutralising stale sweat that has gone rancid.

Buy another shirt (it's not a waste because you can keep using it).

Take a shower, or a torso basin wash if that's the best available.

Apply deodorant.



As much as I want to say the easy answer is to use deodorant it only goes so far and probably won't do the trick as you have noticed :)
You could try mixing up some vinegar and lemon juice, not too much else you will end up sticky and smelling like a fish and chips shop. Just sprits it on every half hour or so and it should get you through the day.
Or just buy your collages nose pegs or better yet open a tin of Surströmming and no one will notice you any more :P
Good luck.

When I was homeless and living in the woods, I discovered that baking soda kills all odors, on bedding and on your person.

Please clarify if you mean just pour baking soda on your clothes, or use it while washing the clothes.

Dry powder inside and outside shirt. If it stings, cut it with talcum powder. Advice from a homeless bumstress.

So I'm sorry but your answer gives a dangerous advise, read this.
